# Scrolling horizontally with a regular mouse on Firefox 8

Tags: firefox, about-config

Sorry for my poor English (I'm learning it).

I've searched on Google and on Super User any way to configure Firefox 8 to scroll horizontally with a regular mouse (2 buttons + scroll wheel), but I could find only solutions that don't seem to work anymore (like that one: http://twob.net/journal/fixing-horizontal-scrolling-in-firefox/).

I would like to be able to scroll a page horizontally scrolling the mousewheel while pressing the SHIFT key. (SHIFT+Mousewheel default action is going back and forward in the browser's history).

For your information, I'm using Firefox 8 under Ubuntu 11.10 (I'm not sure if the O.S. is relevant in this case).

Appreciate any help.

Comment: Is your mouse's scroll wheel clickable (**middle-click**)?

Comment: Yes, it is. But clicking on it on Firefox doesn't show up that "scroll circle" anymore, neither.

Answer (score 2):

There are two methods you can use to get this working:

1. Autoscrolling (middleclick scrolling)
2. IMwheel to emulate horizontal scrolling

### Autoscrolling

It sounds like autoscrolling is disabled in your installation. You can re-enable it by going into Edit->Preferences->Advanced and checking "Use autoscrolling".

### IMwheel

This is a method I was just trying out myself to get Shift scroll working.

1. First, install imwheel:

   ```
     $ sudo apt-get install imwheel
   ```
2. Then copy-paste this into your $HOME/.imwheelrc:

   ```
   "Firefox"
   Shift_L, Up, Button6
   Shift_L, Down, Button7
   Shift_R, Up, Button6
   Shift_R, Down, Button7
   ```
3. Then start imwheel:

   ```
   $ imwheel
   ```

It seems to work for me, but if I scroll too quickly, some of the events get through imwheel and it starts scrolling diagonally instead.

Answer (score 1):

You can install Greasemonkey and use this script: http://userscripts.org/scripts/show/168193
Enjoy!

Answer (score 0):

In Firefox 25.0.1 [on Kubuntu 13.04] I have enabled it by toggling "general.autoScroll" on the about:config page to "true". Now middle-drag (click and hold mousewheel) works for me to enable horizontal scroll and/or vertical scroll by dragging in the direction of desired scroll.